# Bind9 is not solving the names

Tags: networking, server, xubuntu, dns

I need to set up Bind9 just to solve one particular name.
I followed some tutorials but at the end, I can't resolve the name using simple nslookup from another machine.

my /etc/bind/named.conf.local

```
zone "privatelink.file.core.windows.net" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/forward.privatelink.file.core.windows.net";
        allow-transfer {
                10.10.2.8;
        };
};


zone "168.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/reverse.privatelink.file.core.windows.net";
};
```

my forward.privatelink.file.core.windows.net

```
  GNU nano 4.8                                                                               /etc/bind/forward.privatelink.file.core.windows.net                                                                                         
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     privatelink.file.core.windows.net. root.privatelink.file.core.windows.net. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@                       IN      NS      privatelink.file.core.windows.net.
files                   IN      A       10.10.2.8
@                       IN      A       127.0.0.1
@                       IN      AAAA    ::1
```

and then

reverse.privatelink.file.core.windows.net

```
  GNU nano 4.8                                                                               /etc/bind/reverse.privatelink.file.core.windows.net                                                                                         
;
; BIND reverse data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     privatelink.file.core.windows.net. root.privatelink.file.core.windows.net. (
                              1         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      localhost.
1.0.0   IN      PTR     localhost.
files   IN      A       10.10.2.8
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong?
That's what I'm getting in return.

```
nslookup files.privatelink.file.core.windows.net 192.168.168.233
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.168.233

*** UnKnown can't find files.privatelink.file.core.windows.net: Non-existent domain
```

Comment: This is just for clarification: Are you setting up bind9 to resolve a single domain on a private network? In this case, I would recommend unbound, since it is much more lightweight than bind9. I know, not an exact answer, but maybe a suggestion.

Comment: Exactly, for now, it's only that one domain. I will take a look at that as well, thanks!

Comment: I think [unbound](https://github.com/NLnetLabs/unbound) should be simpler to configure as well, as it only has a single configuration file. ;-)

Comment: Your nslookup looks odd, with `Server:  UnKnown`, I would have expected `Server: 192.168.168.233` and I would have expected `Address:  192.168.168.233#53`. Perhaps try to set 192.168.168.233 instead of localhost in your reverse file. Otherwise I don't see an error in the files.